# How to remove the last 6 digits from the filename in Perl using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I need your help in creating a regex to delete the hh:hh:ss bits from the file name.

I have the file name in format of:

> abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720151617.txt

And I want to rename it to:

> abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720.txt

Before moving it to the server. The Perl code I am using is doesn't work.I cannot use SUBSTR or rename function due to script requirement.

```
$file_name = @file_array;
$file_name =~s/$\s+\d{8}(.*)/$1/;
```

Please help me in creating the correct regex to do the same.

Comment: Hint: Use `rename` (part of perl distribution).  `perldoc perlre` might also help.

Comment: "I cannot use SUBSTR or rename function due to script requirement". What does that mean? Even if you use a regex to work out the new filename that you want, you're still going to have to use `rename` to actually change the name of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of focusing on what you don't want, specify a regex that states what you DO want.

In this case, you specifically want to keep the first 8 digits of numbers and truncate the rest:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/\d{8}\K\d+//;
    print;
}

__DATA__
abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720151617.txt
```

Outputs:

```
abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720.txt
```

Or if positive lookbehind assertions are not an option because you're working with a particularly ancient version of perl, then a capture group can achieve the same result:  `s/(\d{8})\d+/$1/;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$filename="abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720151617.txt";
$filename=~s/\d{6}.txt$/.txt/sg;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below perl command,

```
$ echo 'abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720151617.txt' | perl -pe 's/^(.*).{6}(\..*)$/\1\2/g'
abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720.txt
```

So it would be,

```
$file_name =~s/^(.*).{6}(\..*)$/$1$2/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $in = 'abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720151617.txt';

print "$in\n";

my ($new) = $in =~ /(.*2014\d{4})/;

print "$new\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with *non-greedy* way

```
$file_name = 'abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_20140720151617.txt';
$file_name =~s/(.*?)\d{6}\.txt/$1.txt/;

print $file_name;
```